# Armlink -keep option does not recognize token '(' in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, arm

According to [ARM document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0493c/CHDJGJEC.html), to keep an input section from being removed by unused section elimination, one can use `--keep=object(section)`.

However, compiling code in Cygwin, which uses /bin/sh, using the following LDFLAGS returns an error - syntax error near unexpected token `(`'

```
LDFLAGS += --keep=test.o(*my_section_name)
```

The same code works in DOS terminal.

Both DOS and Cygwin use ARM Linker, 4.1 [Build 713]

Comment: Most likely you need to escape, with '\', the star and brackets \\(\\*\\); it works when I do this with a *dash* shell.  The brackets are a special symbol that is used to group commands.  The star is a wildcard for file matching.

Comment: Thank you so much, artless noise! It worked! :)